# Jquery datepicker styles are not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

My page has the following css:

```
 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/Assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="/Assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="/Assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <link href="/Assets/javascripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css"/>
      <link href="/Assets/javascripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.structure.css" />
      <link href="/Assets/javascripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.css"/>
```

When I view source and click on the links, all the .css files are rendering correctly.

When I click on a textbox with a datepicker I just get a bare bones grid of the months dates without any styling.

What could the issue be?

```
all the jquery-ui versions are v1.11.4
bootstrap 3.3.6
jquery 1.12.1
```

Comment: Could you try once without bootstrap and  rest of custom CSS?

Comment: The date picker has a complete [source demo](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) available. It is very simple and it works as it should. Have you compared your code with theirs? If that still does not lead you to the answer please include a a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).